# Problem with gradle and external jar - jar not found

Tags: java, gradle, build, jar, build.gradle

I have a problem with Gradle. I want to use an externally provided Jar: `itext-2.1.7.js6.jar`, it is a patched version used by JasperReports.

In the project structure, I have a `/libs` directory, containing 2 files: `fonts.jar` and `itext-2.1.7.js6.jar`

Part of my gradle.build file looks like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.7.1'
implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports-functions', version: '6.8.0'
implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'
//implementation group: 'hu.blackbelt.bundles.itext', name: 'com.lowagie.itext', version: '2.1.7-1'
```

The last dependency is commented out cause I want to use the external JAR instead of the original iText.

When I am trying to run my app I get:

```
BUILD FAILED in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Could not find com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js6.
Required by:
    project : > net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.7.1
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything is fine with my `fonts.jar`, so I think that it should be the same with iText, but it isn't...

Comment: Have you tried moving the `itext` dependency to the top of the list or else removing all other dependency and running the build then ?

Comment: Have you tried making the `include` parameter not an array? I.e. using just `'*.jar'` rather than `['*.jar']`.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the [`pom` file of `jasperreports`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/6.7.1/jasperreports-6.7.1.pom), there is an explicit dependency on `com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js6` which can also be found in a [specific Jasper Reports repository](http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/)

The reason this works transparently in Maven is that Maven will use the repositories defined in a `pom` file, while Gradle will not use them, as they could be a source of insecurity.

You have two options:

1. Add that repository, potentially using [repository filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec::matching_repositories_to_dependencies) to only serve these artifacts from there and then remove the file from `libs`
2. Add an exclude to `jasperreports`so that it no longer tries to fetch that dependency. And instead the runtime code will use the version found in `libs`. You just forget about transitive dependency management in this case, for example when upgrading `jasperreports` and getting (or not) an updated version from their dependency declaration.